# Google translate on the fly from MySQL database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-translate

Hoping someone has done this before as my searches aren't coming up with anything.

The website I am building has two language sets, Spanish and English. The site has two different domain names (Not bought yet) one for Spanish speakers another for English speakers.

If a user goes to the Spanish domain everything he/she posts is assumed to be primarily in Spanish. So English speaking users that visit the site under the English domain will see that Spanish persons text translated to English. And vice versa for English to Spanish.

Google translate I have found to be the best and it doesn't change non-native language.

My issue is I can't have the "Translate" link on every post that is not in the native language of the navigated domain. I know from my DB which entries are Spanish/English, I need to utilize Google via javascript to translate them as soon as the page has loaded.

I'm hoping someone has done his already.

cheers craig

Comment: To do this using the Google Translate system you will need to use the Google Translate API which is a paid service (http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html) - just FYI.  If the cost is acceptable though, then it would be viable to send off a request each time a post is submitted to the API and then store the translated version for future use (instead of repeatedly calling the service)

Comment: If you want to just translate specific pieces of content I think you need to use the API, unfortunately it's not free anymore.

Comment: The free Google sectional code I used is good enough. I can write out the section code for each instance/post. Isn't there a way to hide the "Translate" link and programmatically call the translate function for each translatable code segment? All outta money, small project and all!!

Comment: The site I'm doing is on the falkland islands. Google translates Falklands to Malvinas and vice Versa. Bing doesn't, I guess no others would either. It's an important factor

Comment: To be honest, I think the rates Google charges for using its Translate API are quite fair. Of course, YMMV.

Comment: I don't know what 20M char's relate to, Mb wise yes but "I want this page to load now users, F5 F5 F5". It may be a fair price, but I'm so skint I'm drinking black coffee atm! The Google pay "api" page say's go look at the free setup they offer. It's good it works, all it needs to do is be behind the scene.

Comment: I'm gonna start from the top, so I'm using: http://translate.google.com/translate_tools and the sectional code. The pay api refers to using this and not to pay!! Now I use that code, my code has to interact, google has to return something! Why can't that simply be done programatically, why does "Translate" have to be physically clicked!!

Comment: I've looked at it, I've tried many things to click that link, all I can guess is that Google somehow is looking up through the parent events and checking them somehow. I think a function whereby you can fake to be those elements may work????

Comment: A teenager can defeat Apple and Sony, but Google's translate interface and no-one on SO has an answer for my question! Yeah right!!!! No, no I'll figure it out myself!!